# Change the year's label in dojo calendar

Tags: javascript, dojo, calendar

I have dojo calendar it's work well about the language that displayed.

but in my country doesn't use A.D. 2012, now use B.E. 2555, I want to changed it.

[image]

How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [dojox.date.buddhist](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/date/buddhist.html#dojox-date-buddhist).

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I'm changing the code to `<input  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="datePackage:'dojox.date.buddhist'" />` It's work.